# Totaling similar input names with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamically-created inputs with names/ids that increase. I want to:

1. Find all blank inputs and fill them with zeros
2. Total up all the numbers entered
3. Put that total into a different input

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

Rows like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Amount1" id="Amount1" value="0" class="Amount">
<input type="text" name="Amount2" id="Amount2" value="" class="Amount">
<input type="text" name="Amount3" id="Amount3" value="10" class="Amount">
<input type="text" name="Amount4" id="Amount4" value="150" class="Amount">
```

and put the total in:

```
<input type="text" name="Totals" id="Totals" value="" class="Totals">
```

This is what I was thinking may work, but isn't even close:

```
$('input[name^="Amount"]').each(function(){
    var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
    emptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
        //total up numbers
          ???
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `return this.value != "";`?

Comment: At what point should the total be calculated and empty input filled with zeros? What event would trigger this?

Comment: What numbers are you wanting totalled up? The numbers after "Amount"?

Comment: @j08691, I have a button that creates new inputs so i put this code inside of that.  So, it creates new inputs, puts zeros is the blanks and totals everything up in one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely that could be done a whole lot easier; the first statement already selects all the input fields you need:

```
var total = 0;

$('input[name^="Amount"]').each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
});

$('#Totals').val(total);
```

*`parseInt()` on an empty value would return `NaN` so I'm using a `|| 0` construct to effectively skip them (i.e. adding `0` to the total).*

Comment: Although all of these answers work your thoughts to watch for NaN is superbe. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

You can just sum them up:

```
var total = 0;

emptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
```

Or with `.map()` and on newer browsers:

```
var total = emptyTextBoxes.map(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10);
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
$(".Amount").each(function() {
    if (this.value == '') { this.value = 0; }
    total += parseInt(this.value);
});
$('.Totals').val(total);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfGbq/